ubicar mi elemento en una sola hoja correspondiente al alto y ancho de mi view port
tengo el siguiente problema de conceptos css, llevo poco tiempo desarrollando en front y me tope con la necesidad de colocar  mi contenido en una sola hoja.
Tengo una barra al inicio de mi hoja (60px - VAR), debajo debe ir un contendedor que ocupa el alto y ancho de mi view port conteniendo un elemento en su interior
algo así:


.recuadro {
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* Ajusta este valor para cambiar la separación horizontal */
  height: calc(100% - 40px); /* Ajusta este valor para cambiar la separación vertical */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fondo{

  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<app-sidenav> </app-sidenav>
<div class="">

  <div class="">

    <router-outlet></router-outlet> /* Apunta div de mas abajo 

  </div>
</div>


<div class="fondo">  
  <div class="recuadro">
    <!-- <app-visorifc></app-visorifc> -->
  </div>
</div>



sucede que mi conteiner se desborda en mi bottom y me genera una barra de navegación vertical por la presencia de mi barra como puedo evitar esto ?


Agrega el código a tu pregunta CSS+HTML

Como puedo añadir el código ?

Pulsas [edit] en tu pregunta, buscar el icono <> y lo presionas. Se abre una ventana que está dividida en 4 (Una para HTML, otra para CSS, otra para javacript y otra que muestra la salida de todo eso). Tú pegas el código donde corresponda (en tu caso solo HTML y CSS) y guardas

bien! ahora si.

La idea es que tu código sea un [MCVE], es decir un código donde se aprecie eso que describes en tu pregunta. A tu código, al menos, le falta el CSS de la parte superior, supongo que son los 40px que están en el calc
